# Swings setSelected() not working for array of JRadioButtons

Tags: java, swing

```
JRadioButton opt[] = new JRadioButton[4];
opt[0].setSelected(false); //not working

JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton();
r1.setSelected(false); //working
```

Can anyone tell my why the first call to `setSelected()` isn't working?

Comment: You should read up the difference between creating an array, and adding elements to the array. It will explain your issue

Answer (score 1):

The default value for elements in a Java `Object` array is `null`. The `JRadioButton` array `opt` has no elements instantiated. You need to to instantiate them prior to invoking any methods:

```
for (int i=0; i < opt.length; i++) {
   opt[i] = new JRadioButton("Radio Button " + i); 
}
```

Comment: Please see the full explanation over here


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699339/setselected-with-jradiobutton-r-new-jradiobutton3-not-working