# setSelected() with JRadioButton r[]=new JRadioButton[3] not working

Tags: java, swing

Here I made a dummy Programme....

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  class MyClass1 implements ActionListener
  {
JFrame fr;
JRadioButton opt[]=new JRadioButton[2];
JButton btnext;
JRadioButton r1;
MyClass1()
{
    fr=new JFrame();
    fr.setLayout(null);
    opt[0]=new JRadioButton("Hello");
    opt[1]=new JRadioButton("Welcome");
    r1=new JRadioButton("Jealsous");
    btnext=new JButton();
    ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(opt[0]);
    bg.add(opt[1]);
    opt[0].setBounds(50,100,200,30);
    r1.setBounds(50,200,200,30);
    opt[1].setBounds(50,150,200,30);
    btnext.setBounds(400,350,100,30);
    fr.add(opt[1]);
    fr.add(opt[0]);
    fr.add(btnext);
    fr.add(r1);
    btnext.addActionListener(this);
    fr.setSize(800,500);
    fr.setVisible(true);
}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(opt[0].getText());
            opt[0].setSelected(false); //not working
            r1.setSelected(false);  //working
        }
    public static void main(String[] s)
        {
            new MyClass1();
        }
    }
```

In this code when I am clicking on button the radiobutton which is an array
opt[0] is still selected.
Whereas radiobutton r1 is not selected  . So basically when I am calling the function setSelected with array of objects it is doing nothing, when me calling with distinct object it is working fine. In the big programme I need of array of objects so that I can use it in for loop and get it initialized to some value coming out of String 2Dimensional Array.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add a description to the problem

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc And it's from the same user...

Comment: opt[i].setSelected(false) /// this statement do nothing because I am using opt array in form of opt[i]...
If I use opt or any other ref var say r1=new JRadioButton() and then use it with r1.setSelected(false) its working fine..
Since I need 4 radio button getting their values from string  [], i cannot use them differently like opt1, opt2,opt3 etc... 
Any help??

Comment: Are you running this code as is or inside some handler/listener?

Comment: Your using i to get the objects in the array but where do you initialize it? The i form the for-loop dosen't exist there.

Comment: @ Sotirios :I am using it in actionListener , The code is very big so thats why cannot post completely here...

Comment: @pad
see the for loop with comment it works 
it set the text from 2d String options which are shown on the form...

Whole code works with button click values changes in radio button just after actionPerformed method the selected radiobutton is still present with new values , as if I choose new value already

Comment: STOP! Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org): short, self-contained, complete, compilable (and runnable) example. This will give a straightforward answer to your issue (if you don't find the issue while trying to create the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: This isn't a duplicate at all. The answer (which I can't enter as a proper answer any more) is: once you enter a `JRadioButton` into a `ButtonGroup` you can't manually deselect it. Instead you have to select one of the other buttons in the group, then the currently selected one will be deselected. Of course you could temporarily remove your button from the group, deselect it, and add it again.

Comment: I really don't understand why didn't you add r1 in the button group

Comment: @Ashish its just an example I forgot to put.

Comment: @Arend : Thanks Mate , I got it...!! You are right if radio buttons are part of button group once any one selected all of them cannot be deselected.. Atleast that's what I have been able to understand..
Tried running code when ButtonGroup is present and when it is nt present , which make me clear and offcoarse your comment. Thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `buttonGroup.clearSelection()`.

but this method is available in java 1.6+ only.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#clearSelection()

```
@Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(opt[0].getText());
            bg.clearSelection();
            r1.setSelected(false);  //working
        }
```

Comment: It's [available in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#clearSelection%28%29) as well?

Comment: @SalilDua Please marked it as a answer. Thanks